# How variables work in Python?

Tags: python, variables, pointers

I've just started to learn Python for a school project but I'm a bit confused with the pointers. Which is weird because I just aced my Assembly exam.

So in this case:

```
var1 = [0, 1]
var2 = [2, 3]

matrix = [
    var1, var2,
    var2, var1
]

newVars = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

If I do this:

```
var1 = newVars[2][:]
var2 = newVars[1][:]
```

The matrix gonna keep the same values as it was before. Because the vars now located to a new address, but the values of the matrix are not.

But obviously if I do this:

```
var1[:] = newVars[2][:]
var2[:] = newVars[1][:]
```

It's gonna change the stored value at the specific memory location.

My questions are the following:

- Am I right with my conclusion?
- Is there any other way I can change the values in the matrix by changing my variables?
- Is there anything else I had to know about the vars in Python?

Comment: It really doesn't help to think in terms of pointers. In Python, you have names, which point at objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is **pass by reference**. This means that when you do:

```
matrix = [
    var1, var2,
    var2, var1
]
```

And you change `var1` or `var2`, it changes the values in the matrix. The matrix has pointers to `var1` and `var2`, and it is not possible to have pure values in python. Instead, you can use `list.copy()` to get a new copy of the variable. `newVars`, on the other hand, is completely unrelated to the other values shown. But when you assign `var1` or `var2` a new value, it is now unrelated to the original matrix. (You changed where it points to, but not the pointer's value itself, so the matrix retains the original value)

A list slicing creates a new object. But since the matrix has pointers to the original object, and `var1` and `var2` simply changed what they point to, the matrix does not change. It's like this:

```
var1 & var2: create a new list and assign its pointer to your self
var1 -> 0x0001
var2 -> 0x0002
matrix: take pointers from var1 and var2 and store it in you.
matrix -> 0x0001, 0x0002.
newVars: create a new list and assign its pointer to your self
newVars -> 0x0004
newVars: create a new list and assign its pointer into your current list (2x)
newVars -> 0x0004: 0x0005, 0x0006
var1 & var2: switch your pointer to a new *copy* of a slice of newVars I have made. (creates new pointers)
var1 -> 0x0007
var2 -> 0x0008
matrix -> 0x0001, 0x0002.
```

Changing `0x0001` changes everything that has a pointer to it, changing a pointer changes `0x0001`, but slicing a list creates a new list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This clarifies everything.